# picker view value

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a picker view in my first view controller.

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent(NSInteger)component{
 switch(row){
  case 1:
   isOne = true;
   break;
  case 2:
   isTwo = true;
   break;
  case 3:
   isThree = true;
   break;
 }
}
```

I want to read this boolean value in my second view controller. How should I do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: I've done this by using delegation myself.

Comment: I don't get this delegation things. any example please

Comment: How do you call the second view controller ? For a tutorial on delegates, try this [link](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/)

Comment: SecondViewController *secController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    secController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:secController animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

finally,  I found the answer:

1. I just have to define a variable string in my first view controller as retain

   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *aString;
2. in the implementaion file set:

   @synthesize aString;
3. in the picker view method:

   ```
   -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row  inComponent:(NSInteger)component { 
          switch (row) {
                  case 0:
                     self.aString = [NSString stringWithString:@"One"];
                     break;
                     .....
   }
   ```

do 1 & 2 in the seconde view controller. and set the selected value from picker view if you switch to the second controller:

```
SecondViewController * secController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
secController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle;
[secController setAString:self.aString];
[self presentModalViewController:secController animated:YES];
```

I don't know if this is the best solution but it works for me right now.